# Constructing structure for wind data

Tags: matlab, for-loop, structure

I have been trying to construct a structure for wind data in matlab using the struct function:

```
struct(fieldname1,value1,fieldname2,value2,......).
```

I have wind speed and direction at different heights such as `40,50,80,90` meters. The problem is I don't understand how to represent the 'value', for my big data.

```
 wind_data=struct(ws40,[],ws50,[],ws80,[],ws90,[],wd40,[],wd50,[],wd80,[],wd90,[])
```

`ws`=wind speed. `wd`=wind direction and each of them are vectors.

Comment: The best format probably depends what you need to do with the data. Why a struct? As speed is not a vector, I'm assuming `ws` and `wd` contain multiple repeats/locations at a given height? In that case, what about a field for each height, containing all the data speed and direction data for that height e.g. `struct("h40",{ws,wd})`. Note the fieldname is a string. So people can help, please add more information about what you plan to do..

Answer (score 0):

You can allocate structs by hand:

```
wind_data.ws40 = [1, 2, 3];
wind_data.wd40 = [4, 5, 6];
wind_data.ws50 = [11, 22, 33];
wind_data.wd50 = [44, 55, 66];
```

or dynamically:

```
heights = [40, 50, 80, 90];
ws      = round(10*rand(4,3));
wd      = round(10*rand(4,3));

for hh = 1:numel(heights)
    wind_data.( [ 'ws' num2str(heights(hh)) ] ) = ws(hh,:)
    wind_data.( [ 'wd' num2str(heights(hh)) ] ) = wd(hh,:)
end
```

or directly allocate them, you have to put the fieldname in `''` as [Ed Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32602171/#comment53060069_32602171) already said:

```
heights = [40, 50, 80, 90];
ws      = round(10*rand(4,3));
wd      = round(10*rand(4,3));

wind_data = struct('ws40', ws(1,:), ...
                   'wd40', wd(1,:), ...
                   'ws50', ws(2,:), ...
                   'wd50', wd(2,:) );
```